# PostgreSQL How to make an AVG on a column on one table based on an insert on another table

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

So here's my problem I have this table providers with a column averageRating which is dependent on the rating of a user which is saved on the table reviews

What I'd like is a function that triggers whenever a new review is inserted

So insert review on review table with a provider_id
=> Function that makes the average of the ratings on the provider with the same provider_id 
 => 
update the averageRating on the provider table

Something along the lines of

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateAvg
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON reviews
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE providers.averageRating SET review.rating = (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM reviews)
```

Comment: so what is the problem?  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, referring to postgres documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html you must create a function to perform your trigger.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION update_average_rating()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE providers SET averageRating = AVG(rating)
  FROM reviews 
  WHERE providers.id = reviews.provider_id 
  AND NEW.provider_id = reviews.provider_id;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER updateAvg
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON reviews
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_average_rating();
```

However, it seems a better solution is use schema design to solve this problem. Wherever you need to display your average rating should be part of a view that takes the average so you can minimize actual cost to your DB performance and retrieve the value on demand as needed.